# facebook login status not working on onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to get Users login status with facebook js sdk. Script works fine when i load it without any onclick event. But when i try to execute the js by firing the onclick only the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` gets updated, But no alert pops up.

```
function upload() {
  function fbLoginStatus(response) {
     if( response.status === 'connected' ) {
        alert("Connected");
     } else if( response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        $('#overlay-shadow').fadeIn(500);
$('#overlay-container').fadeIn(650);
$('#scriptolution-soft-language.scriptolution-soft-box .content').html('<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="collapseAll();" 

class="close-btn badge-language-close"></a><h3>Something is wrong !</h3><br/><h4>Our system got confused. Please try the "Download Cover" 

option. Sorry.</h4>');
     } else {
        alert("Logged Out");
     }
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '414212035337190', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    FB.getLoginStatus(fbLoginStatus);
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', fbLoginStatus);
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
}
```

Comment: The initlaization of FB should be outside of all the other functions. If you trigger upload() on every click, the initialization is done every time. Move the initialization code outside the upload() function .

Comment: @DrColossos After I move it outside upload() function it executes as soon as the page load. Any other way with which I can execute this same function ? Thanks a lot for your valuable reply.